# Naming of Routes for nested resources in Ember.JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

The following route setup is from the Ember.JS docs (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) and I have to deal with an equivalent problem:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
        this.route('edit');
        this.resource('comments', function() {
            this.route('new');
        });
    });
});
```

According to the docs and my own experience this results, among others, in the following route:

```
/post/:post_id/comments -> App.CommentsIndexRoute
```

However, since I want a post-specific comment route I would have expected

```
/post/:post_id/comments -> App.PostsCommentsRoute
```

What exactly is my fallacy and what would I have to change to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `route`'s share their name with their parent `resource`.  If you wanted it to show up as as `PostsCommentsRoute` it would be more like this (note I pluralized it to match your example, despite the url not being pluralized)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
        this.route('comments');
    });
});
```